# Interpretation of VAR results with exogenous variables

Tags: time-series, causality, vector-autoregression, controlling-for-a-variable

I have three time series A, B and C and I ran a VAR using C as a exogenous variable.

I add that the B variable is likely associated with C, in the sense that B could have a casual impact on C.

I found (see below the regression for A as dependent variable) that B is positively and significantly associated with A, and also the exogenous C is positively and significantly associated with A.

My question is: Can I conclude, based on the following results, that the effect of C on A is significant and independent from that of B on A? In other words, can I say something like "keeping the other variables (and especially B) constant (or, controlling for the effect of B), C has a significant positive effect on A"?

Thank you

```
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
A (Lag 1)    0.48795    0.02999  16.273  < 2e-16  ***
B (Lag 1)    0.20429    0.05345   3.822  0.00014  ***
A (Lag 2)    0.21304    0.02975   7.160  1.48e-12 ***
B (Lag 2)   -0.04518    0.05366  -0.842  0.39993    
const        0.90842    0.09045  10.043  < 2e-16  ***
C (exog)     0.27959    0.06543   4.273  2.10e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: I am sorry... the other A and B are the lagged variables. I edited the question

Comment: With "casual impact" I mean that the increase in the values of B can cause an increase in the values C. However this is a theoretical (I would say, hypothetical) stance. I did not test this... I am not specifically interested in the relation between B and C (or B and A) but mostly in the relation between C and A (controlling for the effect of B on A, which could be confounding)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I conclude, based on the following results, that the effect of C on A is significant and independent from that of B on A?

No, you cannot. Since VAR is a linear model, the possibility that the effect of C on A depends on B is explicitly assumed away.

> In other words, can I say something like "keeping the other variables (and especially B) constant (or, controlling for the effect of B), C has a significant positive effect on A"?

If you assume that

1. the model is correct $\quad$ AND
2. the model represents causal relationships (in contrast to merely probabilistic ones),

then you can say that C has a significant positive effect on A, controlling for *lagged* B.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for the conceptual and terminological clarifications

Comment: @kk68, you are welcome!